# Текст внутри ячейки в span

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача: Обернуть текст внутри ячейки в первом столбце в тег span.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Текст при загрузке хочет в span</td>
    <td>Текст без span</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Текст при загрузке хочет в span</td>
    <td>Текст без span</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Были попытки сделать, но не работает почему-то. Вот что у меня есть на данный момент:

```
var myObj = $('table tr td:nth-child(1)');
var myObjLength = $('table tr td:nth-child(1)').length;

for (var i=0; i<myObjLength; i++) {
    var text = myObj[i].text();
    myObj[i].html('<span class="myclass">' + text + '</span>')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('table tr td:nth-child(1)')]
  .forEach(node => { node.innerHTML = `<span class="foo">${node.textContent}</span>`; });
```

```css
.foo { color: red; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Текст при загрузке хочет в span</td>
    <td>Текст без span</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Текст при загрузке хочет в span</td>
    <td>Текст без span</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```